# Посчет в списке кортежей элементов из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список кортежей поризвольной длины, сформированный `itertools.combinations`.
Как пример:

```py
res = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
res = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Имеется список index, как пример:

```py
index = [1, 2]
index = [1, 2, 4]
```

Требуется подсчитать количество совпадений из списка в списке кортежей. Достаточно совпадения одного числа, второе считать не надо. Как пример:

```py
res = [(1, 2),...
index = [1, 2]
```

считается как `count += 1`
Я написал вот такой костыль:

```
for turples in combination:
marker = True
index_list = 0
while marker:
    if index[index_list] in turples:
        count += 1
        marker = False
    else:
        index_list += 1
        if index_list >= len(index):
            marker = False
```

Можно ли сделать это красивее и правильнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю смысл задачи, то так:

```
print(sum(bool(set(t) & set(index)) for t in res))
```

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо за науку. Буду благодарен также, за еще варианты решения, если они есть. Образования для...

Comment: @АлексейПосохов Надеюсь, всё понятно, что тут происходит? Думаю не надо ли написать какое пояснение, но вроде каждое действие тут вполне очевидно.

Comment: если есть общее в 2 множествах == True, пустое множество == False, считает сумму True... Насколько мои знания языка позволяют... Правильно?

Comment: @АлексейПосохов Да, всё так. Вообще, зачастую такие "векторные" и "функциональные" решения выглядят гораздо проще и понятнее, чем когда по спискам идут поэлементно и считают всякие переменные "вручную". Гораздо короче код получается, без лишних элементов и поэтому его проще понимать.

Comment: Ну так я и понимал, что это тот еще костыль, а вот как его переварить в более удобную форму увы... знаний и опыта пока маловато. еще раз спасибо за науку... взял пример на вооружение, что питон и ТАК вот может ;)